# Getting green boxes on monitor, then PC restarts

Tags: gpu, visual-artifacts

I have an Asus Gtx 650Ti Boost. After 4-6 hours of playing a game or browsing the internet, I get green boxes all over the screen and then the PC restarts. After restart, the screen looks normal.

One day after a restart, I let the PC work for about 12 hours, but everything is normal. I replaced the thermal paste, and that didn't help. Then I tried to reflow the card, I used a heat gun for 10 min, but still I didn't fix the problem.

If anyone knows how to fix the problem please let me know.

[image]

[image]

Comment: "Then i tried to reflow the card i used heat gun for 10 min, but still i didn't fix the problem." - Why do people do something like this?  A heat gun is not designed to fix your GPU.  All you are going to do is make the problem worse.  **Your hardware needs to be replaced.**  What you describe is an indication the hardware has failed in some capacity, the failure at this time comes and goes, likely caused by heat causing a electrical short.  **Replace your GPU.**

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately it looks like heat problem as your card under workload overheat. nothing much you can do except to replace the GPU or if you can't  afford it try to cool it down but DO NOT USE HEAT GUN at any form!.

- 1.Download MSI afterburner or similar apps to monitor your your CPU heat during game sessions.

  2. If you overclocking or anything then turn back to normal.
  3. Try to lower game graphic settings to make the card work less hard.(less power = less heat)
  4. open PC case to let the card get more air.
  5. while the case open try to use fan to cool down the card.
  6. try to use maybe newer/older nvidia drivers.

Good luck